# ORDER BY FIELD LIST - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

What i want to do is quite simple:
Write an SQL that will return a bunch of record and order the records by some list of **id** from the **FIELD LIST** section of my SQL

***TABLE SAMPLE***

```
lessons
+----+----------------------+
| id |  name                |
+----+----------------------+
|  9 | Greedy algorithms    |
|  5 | Maya civilization    |
|  3 | eFront Beginner      |
|  2 | eFront Intermediate  |
+----+----------------------+


mod_comp_rule
+----+---------------------+
| id | lesson_id | comp_id |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 |      3    |    1    |
|  2 |      2    |    1    |
|  3 |      9    |    2    |
+----+---------------------+
```

WHAT I WANT TO GET FROM MY QUERY

> SELECT * FROM lessons ORDER BY FIELD(id,'3','2','9') ASC;

**MY SQL**

```
SELECT ls.id, ls.name 
      FROM lessons  ls

      ORDER BY FIELD(ls.id,
      (SELECT mcr.lesson_id FROM  mod_comp_rule mcr 
        INNER JOIN lessons ls ON  ls.id = mcr.lesson_id))
```

**My SQL Query returned the following error**

> MySQL said: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

So how can i make my SQL return FIELD(id,**'3','2','9'**) without flagging the **more than 1 row error** ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why `FIELD()` is needed for this.  A correlated query will do what you want:

```
SELECT ls.id, ls.name 
FROM lessons  ls
ORDER BY (SELECT mcr.id FROM mod_comp_rule mcr WHERE ls.id = mcr.lesson_id);
```

Comment: your are right:: though u have an error in your SQL on **mcr.id**  should be **mcr.lesson_id**

Comment: Right SQL is

SELECT ls.id, ls.name FROM lessons ls ORDER BY (SELECT mcr.lesson_id FROM mod_comp_rule mcr WHERE ls.id = mcr.lesson_id) ASC

Comment: @OkechukwuEze . . . No.  Your sample results show that you want things in the order of 3-2-9.  That is ordering by the `id` not by `lesson_id`.